# How do I get Team Fortress 2 to span multiple monitors?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I'm trying to run TF2 at a custom resolution. I have 3 monitors at 1024x1280 (all together 3072x1280). When I run Team Fortress 2 it only gives me one monitor as the max resolution. I tried setting the startup options in steam to 3000x1200 with the **-w** and **-h**, but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a way to make your monitors look like a single display to TF2?

Comment: At the moment no :/ I need a new display port adaptor, so its three single resolutions.  Other games like FFXIV can do it so I know its possible.

Answer (score 2):

You usually have the setting from AMD's CCC or nvidia's control panel (depending on your GPU) that combines all your monitors into 1 (from window's perspective).  For CCC, it's called "create eyefinity display group".  I've personally never done it with a nvidia card, but it should be an option there for you.

Answer (score 0):

They all need to be the same resolution, refresh rate and have the same sync polarity. You could try changing the 1920x1080 monitors to 1680x1050 and see how that looks. Found this cruising the web..

"For Surround (2D), you can use different monitors sizes. However, each monitor must display the same resolution - and they will default to the lowest common denominator. Two displays at 1680x1050 and one display at 1920x1200 will all display a 1680x1050 image - stretching that image across the 1920x1200 display. If you utilize different aspect rations (i.e., 2x 1920x1080 and 1x 1920x1200), the image on the "odd display" will either be letterboxed or stretched."

Comment: they are all the same.